# Transfering events from custom component to template node

Tags: events, vue.js

I have the following component:

```
<my-button @click="action">Alert</my-button>
```

And it is declared as:

```
<template>
    <button><slot></slot></button>
</template>
```

And

```
export default {
    methods: {
        action: function () {
            alert();
        }
    }
}
```

But on render, I get the message "*Property or method "action" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render*".

What I expects is that my `@click` property on `my-button` be transfered to native `button` specified on the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent component that the `<my-button>` tag is in does not have an `action` method.

You can do any of the following:

1. Add the `@click` handler to the `<button>` tag in the component definition because the `action` method is available at that scope:

   ```
   // Your button component definition
   <template>
     <button @click="action"><slot></slot></button>
   </template>
   ```
2. Move the `action` method to the parent component and add the `.native` modifier to the click event:

   ```
   // Your parent component definition
   <template>
     <my-button @click.native="action">Alert</my-button>
   </template>

   <script>
   export default {
     methods: {
       action: function () {
         alert();
       }
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```

   The `.native` modifier allows the `@click` handler to listen to the native click event of the root element of the `<my-button>` component.
3. Add a `ref` attribute to the `<my-button>` tag, so that you can refer to the button component's `action` method from the parent component:

   ```
   <my-button ref="btn" @click.native="$refs.btn.action()"></my-button>
   ```

Comment: But it is the question... I like to create events directly from HTML code (on `my-button` calling), not on template. Is it possible? I can think in the possibility to create a prop for that, but then I should declare a lot of possible events type (like click, mouse enter and leave, so on).

Comment: The issue with your code is that you specify the click handler function in the parent component as `action`, but the parent component does not have that method. You have to either move the click handler to be inside the button component, or move the `action` method to be in the parent component. See, my updated answer for how to do both.

Comment: Okay, I think I still can not make it understood. I have a HTML page that uses the `my-button` component. It can be used a lot of times, in different contexts. [As in this example](https://pastebin.com/gxbXDmXi).And it is [my-button component](https://pastebin.com/k9V88WR0).

The `my-button` is replaced by an real `button` element, and it seems not "copy" the `@click` defined on component root element.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues yep, in that case you would need to use the `.native` modifier on the click handler. See my answer.

Comment: I have tried but seems that not works on component context. I can use, for instance, `@click.native="this.alert('Hello')"` that does something like the `window.alert()` does, but I can uses like `@click.native="action"` to call the component `action` method (defined inside `my-button.vue { methods: { ... } }`).

Comment: @DavidRodrigues I'm not sure what you are attempting. Can you share the code?

Comment: Fine, I pushed to github.
[1. create vm instance](https://github.com/rentalhost/destiny-activity-report/blob/master/resources/assets/modules/Bootstrap.js), [2. create my-button component](https://github.com/rentalhost/destiny-activity-report/blob/master/resources/assets/vue/Button.vue), [3. uses my-button](https://github.com/rentalhost/destiny-activity-report/tree/master/resources/views/home). Thanks for attention!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143429/discussion-between-thanksd-and-david-rodrigues).